# What does rewrite/2 predicate do in prolog

Tags: prolog

The question is very simple.
What does the `rewrite('A', ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])` predicate do in a prolog program?

What's the use of it? What does it provide?
Please provide some examples in a program.

Comment: This is not a standard Prolog predicate. Where did you see it mentioned?

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged "iso-prolog". `rewrite` is not ISO.